# VT-x is being used by another hypervisor

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am trying to set up a virtual machine using Virtualbox:

- Host OS: Windows 7
- Guest OS: Ubuntu
- Virtualbox version: 5.0.10
- Processor: Core i7-5600U

But when I try to start the VM I got the following error:

> VT-x is being used by another hypervisor (VERR_VMX_IN_VMX_ROOT_MODE).
>   VirtualBox can't operate in VMX root mode. Please close all other virtualization programs. (VERR_VMX_IN_VMX_ROOT_MODE).

I Googled this error and from what I can understand is that I am using another virtualization software, but as far as I know I do no have anything else installed (I had VmWare player installed in the past, but I uninstalled it).

How can I find out what other virtualization software I have?  Or how do I solve this problem?

Comment: How did you uninstall the old player? Did the deinstallation also uninstall its kernel modules (3 of those IIRC).

Comment: I am not sure .I just did uninstall from program and feature in control panel. Not sure about the kernel module though.

Comment: AnyYou could use `lsmod`. If you see items like this then the uninstllation is not complete:<BR>
<BR>
    Module                  Size  Used by<BR>
    vmxnet                 11200  0<BR>
    vmhgfs                 39760  0<BR>

Comment: Isn't lsmod for linux environment ? I am on windows 7.

Comment: @manuj545 - You tagged your question as **Ubuntu.**   I would assume the suggestion would be to run the command within the guest OS.

Comment: It indeed is. I saw Ubuntu and erroniously assumed Ubuntu host, windows guest. So whatever problem you have is somewhere else. Moving to windows 7 virtualisation.. any of those running (besides virtualbox).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this. My machine has bromium vsentry running. which created a mini vm. Hence the VT-x was being used by this. Uninstalled the program and virtualBox started working.
Thanks all for your help

Comment: This was also the root cause behind our entire department not being able to run VirtualBox. Frustratingly, local admin rights is not enough to remove Bromium vSentry - requires Domain Admin to remove :(